# How to speed up parsing json and writing in the database?

Tags: python, json, django, sqlite

I need to parse json file size of 200MB, at the end I would like to write data from the file in sqlite3 database. I have a working python code, but it takes around 9 minutes to complete the task.

```
@transaction.atomic
def create_database():
    with open('file.json') as f:
         data = json.load(f)
         cve_items = data['CVE_Items']


        for i in range(len(cve_items)):
            database_object = Data()
            for vendor_data in cve_items[i]['cve']['affects']['vendor']['vendor_data']:
            database_object.vendor_name = vendor_data['vendor_name']


                for description_data in cve_items[i]['cve']['description']['description_data']:
                    database_object.description = description_data['value']


                for product_data in vendor_data['product']['product_data']:
                    database_object.product_name = product_data['product_name']
                    database_object.save()


                    for version_data in product_data['version']['version_data']:
                        if version_data['version_value'] != '-':
                            database_object.versions_set.create(version=version_data['version_value'])
```

Is it possible to speed up the process?

Comment: Always hard to tell for sure with an ORM obscuring the details of what's actually going on, but I bet it's doing a bunch of inserts without wrapping them all in a transaction, meaning each one is its own transaction. Doing lots of inserts that way is slow, yes.

Comment: @Shawn I have alos tried with transaction.atomic but it did not change the performance. I change code in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all the objects are independent and can be processed in parallel, a simple way would be to use the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module.

Comment: I like the idea. any decent examples of how to read a large json file & insert to sqlite db. (I'm dealing with a 2.5GB json with 2.6M records) 
tried  ijson. currently using a simple 'with open(filename) as lines: for line in lines: (read line and insert using pandas.to_sql, that will take 6 days....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the problem is that the file is large you can use a streaming json parser like [this one](https://pypi.org/project/ijson/)